# An oil jar moving by itself?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, everyday-life

I got this curious mystery and i can't solve It on my own.

I have a small jar, closed , full of olive oil.
I put It months ago up on my cabinet and forgot the existence about It.
The cabinet Is in our kitchen. Only walls near, we live in a country house on the ground floor, the only thing that i thought Is the change of wheater outside: now Is autumn/Winter coming so last two weeks was 25°C High and 9° low temperature.

Last week the jar moved by itself!

Obviusly falling down
from the cabinet : no liquid outside, only the sign of the dust of the moving jar on the cabinet (5/7cm)

Was the temperature of the wheater?

Air entered in the jar (like Pascal's law)

How could the jar move by itself without vibrations?

Comment: How about vibration, from passing trucks, earthquakes, etc.

Comment: Indeed, if ground where jar sits is slightly at an angle with horizontal plane and/or ground has local "micro" pits, then on added ground vibrations, - jar can move quite consistently in the same direction to the lower gravitational potential position, or otherwise just jiggle around in a random walk.